How to optimize data insertion for a large table with over 100 million records into Mysql server
I have a table A with over 100 million records. I want to insert data from another table into this table. Currently, I'm facing a problem with batch inserts: the first few batches insert very quickly, but subsequent batches slow down
 INSERT IGNORE INTO A (
    u_id,
    a_id,
    c_id,
    loc_id,
    fr_owner,
    dis_group_ids,
    created_at,
    updated_at
)
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT
        temp.u_id AS u_id,
        temp.a_id AS a_id,
        temp.c_id AS c_id,
        ca.job_loc_id AS job_loc_id,
        temp.fr_owner AS fr_owner,
        temp.dis_group_ids AS dis_group_ids,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AS created_at,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AS updated_at
    FROM
        TEMP_A AS temp
    INNER JOIN C_A AS ca ON temp.a_id = ca.id
        AND temp.c_id = ca.c_id
    WHERE
        temp.chunk_id = {CHUNK_ID}
        AND temp.file_id = {FILE_ID}
        AND temp.c_id = {C_ID}
    LIMIT
        {LIMIT}
)
SELECT
    temp.*
FROM
    temp
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            A AS cur
        WHERE
            cur.c_id = {C_ID}
    ) cur ON temp.u_id = cur.u_id
    AND temp.a_id = cur.a_id
WHERE
    cur.id IS NULL

I am using batch size for inserts. The first few batches are very fast, but then it slows down. The batch size I use by default is 10,000 records. I think the problem could be due to a database deadlock or table locking. If anyone has experience, please help me with a solution to optimize the insert process.
Can you help me optimize query above or can you share for me some solution to insert data to large tables?

I'd start by including a nice visual EXPLAIN ANALYZE query, so we can understand the query plan and find issues, for example, missing important indexes.

If you have a table without constraints, then inserting subsequent batches (in theory) should not be much slower than the first batches. So, the fact that you experience the contrary means that there are constraints in your table, like unique constraints, check constraints, triggers, keys, indexes and a primary key. All these add checks for your insertions. Let's assume that you have a unique username. In order to ensure that it stays unique, each time you insert a record your system needs to check whether it's still unique. If there are 5 older records, then it's pretty trivial, but if there are 5 000 0000 records from which millions look somewhat like the username you are to insert, then doing this check will be increasingly slower.
Assuming that all your data is reliable and consistent, you can temporarily switch off constraint checks while you move lots of data which will speed up your writing process. But, if stuff is inconsistent, then you will have issues.
You can temporarily disable foreign key constraints.
You can drop all your indexes temporarily and recreate them after you finished inserting all your batches.
